# SQL Query: When I read my BIGINT field into Javascript, it loses precision

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I"m running MS SQL Server 2000. I don't believe the old version is relevant to this issue.

Consider a table with a single BIGINT field called number.

When i transfer this field from the recordset to a variable in Javascript, it loses precision.

Is there any way to convert this field to text in the SELECT statement, before it gets to the Javascript variable?

Comment: How are you calling SQL Server from JavaScript?

Comment: I'm coding in ASP classic, and i'm using an ActiveX Data Object to return a Recordset, with a SELECT statement like "SELECT number FROM table ORDER BY number;"

Comment: Select cast(YourBigInt as varchar(25))

Comment: I have to ask,  how does a BIGINT lose precision?

Comment: Changes to a different number, is what i mean. 1000000000000000001 becomes 1000000000000000000. I'll try using the cast method, thanks.

Comment: @AWilliams, please post your JavaScript ADO code snippet. What provider/driver are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your attention Dan but the CAST function was just what i needed.